# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Been looking every where for a tutorial or something.

I've been trying to implement my old generic repository pattern for MVC5 into a new MVC6 project.

I set up 3 class library's `.Core`, `.Data` and `.Service`, However there's an issue with `IDBset`, seems my intellisense doesn't like it, I tried to add `System.Data` and Entity framework 6 but without any luck (cant find it...confusing).

After roaming google I decided to ask here, is there a tutorial with the correct way or can someone throw up a very simple MVC6 Generic Repository pattern? I have a feeling the Old method of doing it may have changed, just cant seem to find any information other than the inbuilt DI.

Code:
my `IDbContext` interface

```
IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity;
```

does not see `IDbSet`, this simply because of Entity Framework? I do have the References to it.

Issue may be i cant find the using statment for entity framework.

UPDATE:

Using Entity framework 8.0.0 beta.  Change all IDbset references to DbSet.

However in my generic repository where i use methods such as:

```
public virtual T GetById(object id)
{
    return this.Entities.Find(id);
}
```

"Find" isnt a method.  and i can no longer use "DbEntityValidationException" in  my catchs.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to show some code .Also I mean that "IDBSet" is located in `EntityFramework.dll`

Comment: sure ill grab some of my code

Comment: Do you reference Entity Framework 6.1.3 intentionally? ASP.NET 5 comes with [Entity Framework 7](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework), but that is complete rewrite.

Comment: 7 isnt stable is it?  actually, hmm, i should use 7 as its built with asp.net 5 inmind.

Comment: No, EF7 is part of ASP.NET 5 and will be released in parallel. The latest 'stable beta' is [beta8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServer).

Comment: updated my question.  EF 7 doesnt contain some parts required for generic repos setup like back in 6.

Comment: "Using Entity framework 8.0.0 beta" ... no such thing. Did you been EF7, beta8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework 7 Beta 8 doesn't come with the Find Method. It will probably be added before the final release.

You will have to use the  the `FirstOrDefault` method instead until that happens

```
public virtual T GetById(int id)
{
    return this.Entities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Because `Id` property will not be recognized you'll have to add an interface and make your repository implement it.

```
public interface IEntity
{
     int Id { get; set; }
}
```

e.g.

```
 public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T: class, IEntity
```

From the [github issues list](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3322). EF7 does not perform automatic data validation so DbEntityValidationException does not exist in EF7.

Take note: EF7 is not a update of EF but a rewrite.

Comment: need to cast in this case,  x=> x.Id == (int) id

Comment: what about "DbEntityValidationException" this doesnt appear to be in entity anymore is there an alternative?

Comment: ah shame thats been dropped

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework 7 `IDbSet` itself represents an implementation of Repository pattern.

```
/// <summary>
///     A DbContext instance represents a session with the database and can be used to query and save
///     instances of your entities. DbContext is a combination of the Unit Of Work and Repository patterns.
/// </summary>
```

> Source: GitHub EntityFramework7 repo, [DbContext.cs  24-27 line](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1c9db6d4009149ad3e4091d62cb6fbc15adec33b/src/EntityFramework.Core/DbContext.cs)

And `DBContext` it's implementation of [UnitOfWork](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)

Comment: sorry are you trying to say i dont need repos pattern as entity already impliments one?

Comment: @SteveSmithSkId yep, devs from Microsoft made some architectural changes for EntityFramework and just implemented Context stuff in the way we usually do in MVC Framework. Now it looks for me as redundant piece of code.. to implement UoW and Repositories in ASP.NET 5 - MVC 6... Also they added architectural possibility to create own data context for any kind of databases.. wether relational or nosql

Comment: There is no IDbSet  any more (EF Core). Just wonder why they have removed it.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary of firste's answer, I'm not confident by using FirstOrDefault, cause it will generates a SELECT TOP 1 [...].

In many cases, the Id should be unique, but sometimes you can have bad designed Db's. If not, your application should throws an exception (that's what we're looking after).

So, until EF7 implements a Find() method, I strongly suggest using **SingleOrDefault()** :

```
public virtual T GetById(int id)
{
    return this.Entities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Like that, you add an application control to verify that Id should be unique, taking no cares if the Db is correctly done or not. It add another level of security to your business.