# Why EF7 doesn't have Find method?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I installed asp.net 5 and Ef 7 rc1
And i m trying to write a generic repository and i need the **find** method
For the "get" method , but it doesn't exists
Is it on purpose , is there an alternative? is it a bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DbSet doesn't have a Find method in EF7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030472/dbset-doesnt-have-a-find-method-in-ef7)

Comment: A solution of using a generic repository to get around the Find limitation was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647984/asp-net-5-mvc-6-generic-repository-pattern/33649430#33649430

Answer (score 3):

It is not yet implemented.

See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/797 for more details about it

Answer (score 0):

It was included in the [Entity Framework Core 1.1 Preview 1 version](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/25/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1-preview-1/) with exactly the same behavior of EF 6.x, if the entity is already loaded into the context, then it is returned without querying the database, so it will remain in later version of EF Core

Answer (score 0):

It was included in the Entity Framework Core 1.1 Preview 1 version with exactly the same behavior of EF 6.x, if the entity is already loaded into the context, then it is returned without querying the database, so it will remain in later version of EF Core